# Dynamicly changing the QWidget in PyQt5 in paintevent

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class CircleWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, color = 'green'):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(150, 150)
        self.color = color
        self.qt_color = Qt.green

    def paintEvent(self, event = None):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QPen(self.qt_color, 8, Qt.SolidLine))
        qp.setBrush(QBrush(self.qt_color, Qt.SolidPattern))
        qp.drawEllipse(40, 40, 100, 100)
        self.change_color()
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.change_color)
        timer.start(2*100)

    def change_color(self):
        if self.color == 'red':
            self.qt_color = Qt.red
        elif self.color == 'green':
            self.qt_color = Qt.green
```

Hey guys.
I have a code just like above and i want it to update the Gui as well.But i don't know how. The **self.qt_color** is updated all the time perfectly but i have no idea how to make it draw the **QWidget** again with the right color every 2 seconds or so.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the value of `self.qt_color`, you have to request for an update of your widget by calling `update()` which will create a paint event.

Don't create your timer in `paintEvent`: it will create a new timer each time the function is called.

```
class CircleWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, color = 'green'):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(150, 150)
        if color == 'red':
            self.qt_color = Qt.red
        elif color == 'green':
            self.qt_color = Qt.green

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.change_color)
        self.timer.start(2*1000) # Only one timer is needed

    def paintEvent(self, event = None):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QPen(self.qt_color, 8, Qt.SolidLine))
        qp.setBrush(QBrush(self.qt_color, Qt.SolidPattern))
        qp.drawEllipse(40, 40, 100, 100)


    def change_color(self):
        if self.qt_color == Qt.red:
            self.qt_color = Qt.green
        else:
            self.qt_color = Qt.red
        self.update() # Will call paintEvent
```

The circle will alternate between red and green every 2 seconds

Comment: hey man,
But one problem, in my original code it was doing it properly and based on that the color of circle should be read or green so basically it should work like this:
1. based on persons choice in different widget the **self.color** is updated to 'red' or 'green' - it was done in my previous code correctly, if that's matter
2. based on that **self.color** every 2 sec, the self.qt_color should be updated to Qt.green or Qt.red
3. After that the Widget should be "repainted" or something with the current - correct color :)

Answer (score 0):

'''

```
    self.color = color
    if self.color == 'red':
        self.qt_color = Qt.red
    elif self.color == 'green':
        self.qt_color = Qt.green

def change_color(self):
    if self.color == 'red':
        self.qt_color = Qt.red
    elif self.color == 'green':
        self.qt_color = Qt.green
    self.update() # Will call paintEvent
```

'''
Thank you Romha Korev, based on what you wrote i edited your answer with the above code and now it works perfectly :)

Comment: Don't forget to move the timer outside `paintEvent`. You'll create a new timer every 2 seconds, otherwise

Comment: again :) thank you for your help. It's working exactly like i need it.